# Fragments not working?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to create multi fragments. When device is in portrait mode the list fragment and detail fragment should replace each other and when the device rotates the list and detail fragment should display side by side i.e., 50-50. However, I'm not getting my desired results the UI is blank/ error in `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`.
**Here is my code**

**DetFrag.java (Detail Fragment)**

```
 public class DetFrag extends Fragment {


        public DetFrag() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_det, container, false);
        }

    }
```

**Listfrag.java (List Fragment)**

```
public class Listfrag extends ListFragment {
    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        myList.add(0, "1");
        myList.add(1, "2");
        myList.add(2, "3");
        myList.add(3, "4");
        myList.add(4, "5");


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
        setListAdapter(myAdapter);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fManag = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fTrans ;

        if (findViewById(R.id.fragHolder) == null) {
            Fragment flist = fManag.findFragmentById(R.id.listFrag);
            Fragment fDet = fManag.findFragmentById(R.id.detFrag);
            fTrans = fManag.beginTransaction();
            fTrans.add(R.id.listFrag, flist);
            fTrans.add(R.id.detFrag, fDet);
            fTrans.commit();
        }
        else {
            Fragment list = fManag.findFragmentById(R.id.fragHolder);
            fTrans = fManag.beginTransaction();
            fTrans.add(R.id.fragHolder, list);
            fTrans.commit();
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Portrait.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
       }
       }
```

**Portrait.java (To start new activity when in portrait)**

```
public class Portrait extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_portrait);

        FragmentManager fManag = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fTrans ;

        Fragment detFrag = fManag.findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragHolder);
        fTrans = fManag.beginTransaction();
        fTrans.add(R.id.detailFragHolder, detFrag);
        fTrans.commit();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml (portrait)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragHolder"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**landscape(activity_main)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listFrag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detFrag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_det.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="oryx.com.blueprint.DetFrag">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_portrait.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/detailFragHolder">


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_det, container, false);
        }
```

Use this:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detFrag, container, false);
        return view;
    }
```

And instead of this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
    setListAdapter(myAdapter);
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Use this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listFrag, container, false);
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
setListAdapter(myAdapter);
return view;
}
```

Comment: Please dont forget to mark this post as answer if it works for you.Happy Coding :)

Comment: hey! but detFrag and listFrag are my id not layouts and also ListFragment don't have a layout to inflate.